# trigger app level style changes from a child component

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

When I am in a child component, I would like to change the entire page background (including app-nav-bar) to a different color from the default color.

When I move to a different component, the default style should be returned.

Any ideas people?

Comment: Are you using a Bool value to toggle that child component? Or are you using a different method to activate the child component?

Comment: I am going to the child component using router

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `Vuetify theme`?
Theme can contain set of colors

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/

You can change black and white theme by
`this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true/false` in component

Comment: but how does a theme change the entire background (including app-nav-bar) of app? it will only change the container. correct?

Comment: @chaitanyam it depends on how you use the theme, you can use `computed` property to set `backgroundColor` of any element you need

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer to my comment, this is what you probably want to do:
Set up the Vuex store and store variables with color codes in there.
This way you can access these colors from everywhere in your app.
Then, in your App, you can check for the current route with:

```
this.$route
```

So then you could check if the route matches the route where you want to change the color.
Then apply the color to all elements.

PS.
If you only want to change elements that can be found in app.vue, you don't have to store the variables in the store at all, but you can simply check in your router and assign the colors accordingly.

Hope this helped you!